# fixed pseudo-random binary sequence (prbs)

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, rtl

On recent comments based fixed modules for FPGAs for generating a pseudo-random bit sequence are presented. The first module generates a bit sequence. The third module speeds up the generation by transferring the bus to, for example, a multiplexer which is controlled by a faster device. Hence this bus is serialized into a bit sequence.

prbs.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module prbs #
(
    parameter integer PN = 7 //3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 23, 31, 32, 36, 41
)
(
    input  logic i_clk,
    input  logic i_s_rst_n,
    input  logic i_en,

    output logic o_prbs,
    output logic o_prbs_n
);
    localparam integer TAP_1 = (PN == 3) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 4) ? 3 :
                               (PN == 5) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 6) ? 5 :
                               (PN == 7) ? 6 :
                               (PN == 9) ? 8 :
                               (PN == 10) ? 9 :
                               (PN == 11) ? 10 :
                               (PN == 15) ? 14 :
                               (PN == 17) ? 16 :
                               (PN == 18) ? 17 :
                               (PN == 20) ? 19 :
                               (PN == 21) ? 20 :
                               (PN == 22) ? 21 :
                               (PN == 23) ? 22 :
                               (PN == 25) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 28) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 29) ? 28 :
                               (PN == 31) ? 30 :
                               (PN == 33) ? 32 :
                               (PN == 35) ? 34 :
                               (PN == 36) ? 35 :
                               (PN == 39) ? 38 :
                               (PN == 41) ? 40 : 0;

    localparam integer TAP_0 = (PN == 3) ? 1 :
                               (PN == 4) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 5) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 6) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 7) ? 5 :
                               (PN == 9) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 10) ? 6 :
                               (PN == 11) ? 8 :
                               (PN == 15) ? 13 :
                               (PN == 17) ? 13 :
                               (PN == 18) ? 10 :
                               (PN == 20) ? 16 :
                               (PN == 21) ? 18 :
                               (PN == 22) ? 20 :
                               (PN == 23) ? 17 :
                               (PN == 25) ? 21 :
                               (PN == 28) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 29) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 31) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 33) ? 19 :
                               (PN == 35) ? 23 :
                               (PN == 36) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 39) ? 34 :
                               (PN == 41) ? 37 : 0;

    logic [PN - 1 : 0] lfsr; 

    assign o_prbs   = lfsr[PN - 1];
    assign o_prbs_n = ~o_prbs;                      

    always_ff @ (posedge i_clk) begin
        if (i_s_rst_n == 1'h0) begin
            lfsr <= '1;
        end
        else if (i_en == 1'h1) begin
            lfsr <= {lfsr[PN - 2 : 0], lfsr[TAP_1] ^ lfsr[TAP_0]};
        end
    end
endmodule
```

prbs_tb.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module prbs_tb; 
    localparam integer PN             = 7; //3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 23, 31, 32, 36, 41
    localparam integer PERIOD         = 2 ** PN;

    localparam integer CLOCK_PERIOD   = 100;

    localparam integer TEST_ITERATION = 1000;
    localparam integer CHANGE_EN_VAL  = 100;

    bit clk     = '0;
    bit s_rst_n = '0;
    bit en      = '0;
    
    logic prbs  ;
    logic prbs_n;

    integer tick = 0;

    prbs #
    (
        .PN (PN)
    )
    prbs_dut
    (
        .i_clk     (clk    ),
        .i_s_rst_n (s_rst_n),
        .i_en      (en     ),

        .o_prbs    (prbs   ),
        .o_prbs_n  (prbs_n )
    );

    always begin
         #(CLOCK_PERIOD / 2) clk = !clk;
    end

    initial begin
        s_rst_n <= '0;
        @(posedge clk);

        s_rst_n <= '1;
        en      <= '1;
        @(posedge clk);

        for(int i = 0; i < TEST_ITERATION; i++) begin
            if ((i % PERIOD) == (PERIOD - 1)) begin
                en   <= ~en;
                tick = 0;
            end
            else begin
                tick++;
            end

            @(posedge clk);
        end
        
        $stop();
    end
endmodule
```

prbs_wide.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module prbs_wide #
(
    parameter integer PN = 7, //3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 23, 31, 32, 36, 41
    parameter integer WIDTH = 16
)
(
    input  logic                 i_clk,
    input  logic                 i_s_rst_n,
    input  logic                 i_en,

    output logic [WIDTH - 1 : 0] o_prbs,
    output logic [WIDTH - 1 : 0] o_prbs_n
);
    localparam integer TAP_1 = (PN == 3) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 4) ? 3 :
                               (PN == 5) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 6) ? 5 :
                               (PN == 7) ? 6 :
                               (PN == 9) ? 8 :
                               (PN == 10) ? 9 :
                               (PN == 11) ? 10 :
                               (PN == 15) ? 14 :
                               (PN == 17) ? 16 :
                               (PN == 18) ? 17 :
                               (PN == 20) ? 19 :
                               (PN == 21) ? 20 :
                               (PN == 22) ? 21 :
                               (PN == 23) ? 22 :
                               (PN == 25) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 28) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 29) ? 28 :
                               (PN == 31) ? 30 :
                               (PN == 33) ? 32 :
                               (PN == 35) ? 34 :
                               (PN == 36) ? 35 :
                               (PN == 39) ? 38 :
                               (PN == 41) ? 40 : 0;

    localparam integer TAP_0 = (PN == 3) ? 1 :
                               (PN == 4) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 5) ? 2 :
                               (PN == 6) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 7) ? 5 :
                               (PN == 9) ? 4 :
                               (PN == 10) ? 6 :
                               (PN == 11) ? 8 :
                               (PN == 15) ? 13 :
                               (PN == 17) ? 13 :
                               (PN == 18) ? 10 :
                               (PN == 20) ? 16 :
                               (PN == 21) ? 18 :
                               (PN == 22) ? 20 :
                               (PN == 23) ? 17 :
                               (PN == 25) ? 21 :
                               (PN == 28) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 29) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 31) ? 27 :
                               (PN == 33) ? 19 :
                               (PN == 35) ? 23 :
                               (PN == 36) ? 24 :
                               (PN == 39) ? 34 :
                               (PN == 41) ? 37 : 0;

    logic [PN - 1 : 0] lfsr;
    logic [PN - 1 : 0] r_lfsr;  
    logic [WIDTH - 1 : 0] tmp;  
    
    always_comb begin
        lfsr = r_lfsr;

        for (int i = WIDTH - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
            lfsr   = {lfsr[PN - 2 : 0], lfsr[TAP_1] ^ lfsr[TAP_0]};
            tmp[i] = lfsr[TAP_1] ^ lfsr[TAP_0];
        end
    end                 

    always_ff @ (posedge i_clk) begin
        if (i_s_rst_n == 1'h0) begin
            r_lfsr   <= '1;

            o_prbs   <= '0;
            o_prbs_n <= '1;
        end
        else if (i_en == 1'h1) begin
            r_lfsr <= lfsr;

            o_prbs   <= tmp;
            o_prbs_n <= ~tmp;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

prbs_wide_tb.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module prbs_wide_tb;
    localparam integer PN             = 7;
    localparam integer PERIOD         = 2 ** PN - 1;
    localparam integer WIDTH          = 128;

    localparam integer CLOCK_PERIOD   = 100;

    localparam integer TEST_ITERATION = 1000;
    localparam integer CHANGE_EN_VAL  = 100;

    bit clk     = '0;
    bit s_rst_n = '0;
    bit en      = '0;

    logic [WIDTH - 1 : 0] prbs  ;
    logic [WIDTH - 1 : 0] prbs_n;

    prbs_wide #
    (
        .PN    (PN   ),
        .WIDTH (WIDTH)
    )
    prbs_wide_dut
    (
        .i_clk     (clk    ),
        .i_s_rst_n (s_rst_n),
        .i_en      (en     ),

        .o_prbs    (prbs   ),
        .o_prbs_n  (prbs_n )
    );

    always begin
         #(CLOCK_PERIOD / 2) clk = !clk;
    end

    initial begin
        s_rst_n <= '0;
        @(posedge clk);

        s_rst_n <= '1;
        en      <= '1;
        @(posedge clk);

        for(int i = 0; i < TEST_ITERATION; i++) begin        
            if ((i % PERIOD) == PERIOD - 1) begin
                en <= ~en;
            end
            @(posedge clk);
        end
        
        $stop();
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see too much room for improvement.

Since you have some code which is common to 2 modules (the `localparam` `TAP_0` and `TAP_1` declarations), you could move them to a separate file and `include` them into the modules:

```
`include "common.v"
```

You could consider replacing the multiple conditional operators used to define `TAP_0` and `TAP_1` with `case` statements.  To do so, you would also need to place the code inside a `function`.  In general, functions are synthesizable.

```
localparam integer TAP_0 = tap0(PN);

function integer tap0 (integer pn);
    case (pn)
         3      : return  1;
         4, 5   : return  2;
         6, 9   : return  4;
         7      : return  5;
        10      : return  6;
        11      : return  8;
        15, 17  : return 13;
        18      : return 10;
        20      : return 16;
        21      : return 18;
        22      : return 20;
        23      : return 17;
        25      : return 21;
        28, 36  : return 24;
        29, 31  : return 27;
        33      : return 19;
        35      : return 23;
        39      : return 34;
        41      : return 37;
        default : return  0;
    endcase
endfunction
```

It is often beneficial to encapsulate complex code like this inside a `function`; it may make the code easier to understand.

A benefit of using `case` is that you can group inputs together which return the same value; this is done using a comma to separate the case items, such as `4, 5`.  This results in fewer lines of code.

This is all a matter of preference and, of course, tool support.

For `TAP_1`:

```
localparam integer TAP_1 = tap1(PN);

function integer tap1 (integer pn);
    case (pn)
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          9,
         10,
         11,
         15,
         17,
         18,
         20,
         21,
         22,
         23,
         25,
         28,
         29,
         31,
         33,
         35,
         36,
         39,
         41     : return pn-1;
        default : return 0;
    endcase
endfunction
```

Here, all explicit case items return the simple expression `pn-1`.  You can add as many of the case items on the same line as you want instead of having them one per line.

I attempted to use a `case inside` construct, but the 2 simulators I tried it on generated compile errors due to an unsupported construct.  Maybe it will be supported in a future release.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.5.4 *Set membership case statement*.